# React Context API - rerender component on context change without wrapping render in a consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using this.context to get context data inside the lifecycle methods, but when I am not wrapping component with Consumer, then when context data changes, my component is not getting rerendered.

So instead of this:

```
render() {
        console.log('companies render');
        const { modal, singleCompanyData, loading } = this.state;
        const { itemsPerPage } = this.props;
        const columns = [
            { key: 'id', title: 'ID' },
            { key: 'title', title: 'Title' },
            { key: 'city', title: 'City' },
            { key: 'btn', title: 'Action' }
        ];
        return (
            <SharedDataConsumer>
                {({ companies }) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <Companies
                            columns={columns}
                            data={companies}
                            addCompany={this.addCompany}
                            totalRecords={companies.length}
                            loading={loading}
                            itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
                        />
                        <AM2Modal open={modal} handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}>
                            <CompaniesEdit
                                singleCompanyData={singleCompanyData}
                                handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}
                                inputChangeEvent={this.inputChangeEvent}
                            />
                        </AM2Modal>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )}
            </SharedDataConsumer>
        );
    }
```

I need to use something like this, in order to format that data before render:

```
render() {
        console.log('companies render');
        const { modal, singleCompanyData, loading } = this.state;
        const { companies } = this.context;
        const { itemsPerPage } = this.props;
        const newComp = companies.map(value => ({
           ...value,
           btn: this.actionBtns(value.id)
        }));
        const columns = [
            { key: 'id', title: 'ID' },
            { key: 'title', title: 'Title' },
            { key: 'city', title: 'City' },
            { key: 'btn', title: 'Action' }
        ];
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Companies
                    columns={columns}
                    data={newComp}
                    addCompany={this.addCompany}
                    totalRecords={companies.length}
                    loading={loading}
                    itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
                />
                <AM2Modal open={modal} handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}>
                    <CompaniesEdit
                        singleCompanyData={singleCompanyData}
                        handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}
                        inputChangeEvent={this.inputChangeEvent}
                    />
                </AM2Modal>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
```

But this way, component is not getting updated after context changes - context data is async.

I did research and saw this example where they wrap export and pass context data as props, but not sure if thats the correct way to go with latest context API?

Full code [here.](https://gist.github.com/goranefbl/67c61eac0006148783535a76d4179cc7)

Comment: what version of react do you use

Comment: I am using the latest version.